# Cómo autenticarse mediante roles evitando la autenticación anonima en symfony

Tags: php, login, validación, symfony3, twig

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio para clase con symfony3, estamos probando a hacer un login y que éste, dependiendo de el rol que hayamos establecido, nos deje loguearnos o no, la primera parte fue hacerlo a través del formulario que genera el navegador automáticamente y ahí si era capaz de loguearme con un usaurio concreto, pero ahora, la segunda parte, tuvimos que crear un formulario en una plantilla twig, y no se donde está el fallo o que debería modificar para que me reconociera a los usuarios, porque me entra como anónimo ponga lo que ponga en el formulario.

Controlador:

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;

class SecurityController extends Controller
{
   /**
   * @Route("/login", name="login_route")
   */
   public function loginAction()
   {
      $autenticacion = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');
      $error = $autenticacion->getLastAuthenticationError();
      return $this->render('Security/login.html.twig', array(
      'error' => $error
      ));
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/login_check", name="login_check")
    */
    public function loginCheckAction()
    { 
        return $this->render('Security/login_check.html.twig');
     }

}
```

plantilla twig:

```
{% extends "base.html.twig" %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  <style type = "text/css">
     body {
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size:14px;
     }
     label {
        font-weight:bold;
        width:100px;
        font-size:14px;
     }
     .box {
        border:#666666 solid 1px;
     }
  </style>
 {% endblock %}

 {% block body %}

  <div align = "center">
     <div style = "width:300px; border: solid 1px #333333; " align = "left">
        <div style = "background-color:#333333; color:#FFFFFF; padding:3px;"><b>Login</b></div>

        <div style = "margin:30px">

           <form action = "{{ path('login_check') }}" method = "post">
              <label>UserName  :</label><input type = "text" name = "_username" class = "box"/><br /><br />
              <label>Password  :</label><input type = "password" name = "_password" class = "box" /><br/><br />
              <input type = "submit" value = " Submit "/><br />
           </form>

            {# Se introduce el posible mensaje de error si existiese #}
            {% if error %}
            <div style = "font-size:11px; color:#cc0000; margin-top:10px">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  {% endblock %}
```

Security.yml

security:

```
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-configuring-how-users-are-loaded
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory:
            users:
                usuario1:
                    password: abc123.
                    roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'
                usuario2:
                    password: abc123.
                    roles: 'ROLE_GUEST'
                cisco:
                    password: abc123.
                    roles: 'ROLE_USER'

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        anonymous: ~
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
        http_basic: ~

        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
        form_login:
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /loginCheck

#indicamos el control de acceso para limitar el permiso de entrada a la ruta de un determinado tipo de usuario
#los roles empiezan por ROLE_ y suiquen con la definición que queramos darle ej ROLE_1 || ROLE_ALUMNO || ROLE_LOQUEQUIERAS
access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_GUEST } #para acceder con el usuario2
        - { path: ^/guest, roles: ROLE_USER } #para acceder con cisco
        #- { path: ^/anonimo, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } #para acceder anonimamente

# Esta línea indicará cómo se enviará la contraseña desde el cliente al servidor. Se le indica en testo plano.
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```